# Adding image to DataGridViewImageColumn in c#

Tags: c#, image, datagridviewcolumn

i am trying to add an image to DataGridViewImageColumn via code or even at deaign time

it always comes to a default c# image with 'x' indicating no image

i tried this code from microsoft

```
    Icon treeIcon = new Icon(this.GetType(), "tree.ico");
DataGridViewImageColumn iconColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
iconColumn.Image = treeIcon.ToBitmap();
iconColumn.Name = "Tree";
iconColumn.HeaderText = "Nice tree";
dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(2, iconColumn);
```

.however i added an .ico to the resource -also tried the file path-an exception results said that tree.ico not found in form class

I replaced the icon with an Image

```
            ataGridViewImageColumn img = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
            img.ValuesAreIcons = true;
            Image image = Image.FromFile("C:/Users/../Desktop/app_edit.png");
            img.Image = image;
            showprocessed_dataGridView.Columns.Add(img);
            img.HeaderText = "Image";
            img.Name = "img";
```

This results to the default "no image" displayed in the ataGridViewImageColumn what is the solution to this issue ? Is the matter with image format or what !!
Any help would be appreciated ..

Comment: Does the user the progam is running as have permissions to read `"C:/Users/../Desktop/app_edit.png"`?

Comment: this is not the issue at the moment because i will include it within the application resources >> just the problem is adding image and display it through the grid ..

Answer (score 0):

The code from Microsoft looks like it's changing the image in the column's *header*. It does not add a row that contains an image. To do that you need to add a record to the data source you bind to the `DataGridView` which contains proper image data or manually create a `DataGridViewRow` which you add to the `DataGridView`.

Comment: so what!! it doesn't matter to change the default image or as i created a row and set some image to the dataGridViewImageColumn 
than added it to the Datagridview >> Just both ways i can't display my image if any have tried this please provide an answer

Comment: Ok, your question is about adding an image to a column, something for which you suppose you have the source - I just wanted to tell you that you don't have the source for what you think you have it for. There actually *is* a difference in whether you want to change the caption image or add a row that contains an image, which is what I explained also. Maybe it would help to remove the `img.ValuesAreIcons = true;` line - your image is not an icon, but a PNG.

Comment: About the `img.ValuesAreIcons` property: *Gets or sets the image displayed in the cells of this column when the cell's Value property is not set and the cell's ValueIsIcon property is set to false.*

Comment: Well that is my source : 
'DataGridViewImageColumn img = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
Image image = Image.FromFile("C:/Users/../Desktop/app_edit.png");
            img.Image = image;'

Comment: i also tried to set 'img.ValuesAreIcons= false; ' thats not the solution

Comment: Yes, with this code you're adding a column to the `DataGridView`, but you're not adding a *row* that displays any data.

Answer (score 0):

use RowDataBound event to bind the images to grid,

```
protected void gridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
 if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
 {
  Image imgGridview = (Image) e.Row.FindControl("imgGrv");
  imgGridview.ImageUrl = "images/test.gif";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this may help you

```
 DataGridViewImageColumn delCol = new DataGridViewImageColumn();//create image column
                delCol.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom;//column properties
                int icIndex = DGV_showTable.Columns.Add(delCol);//add column to DGV
                DGV_showTable.Columns[icIndex].Name = "Delete";//set name for column

                Image image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\mohab.MOHAMMED\Desktop\delete.png");//load img png
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGV_showTable.Rows)//foreach on all rows
                {

                    row.Cells["Delete"].Value = image;//loadimage to dgv on spicific column
                }
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to change `img.ValuesAreIcons` from `true` to `false` on the second code that you wrote it.
It will works, it happened to me when I used your code to fix this problem.